# Android studio properties tab items indented too far (unable to see anything)

Tags: java, android, properties, tabs

I am new to Android Studio so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have a Microsoft Surface book that I am using to code on. Surface books have a native resolution of 3000x2000. I am currently taking an android development course but it is extremely frustrating to use Android Studio because it is hard for me to see the name of certain properties in the properties tab. The reason is that the item names are so tabbed in that they get cut off by the value field. I have to extend the properties tab about halfway across the screen just to be able to see the properties.

I have searched all through the Android Studio settings, as well as google but haven't come across a single reference of the problem. (I guess not many people code on high res displays.)

Is there any way I can fix this so I can actually have the properties tab a decent size on my screen when I am working in Android Studio?

Take a look at the screenshots in the folder linked below to get an idea of what im talking about.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5kPv_r1P45vVmdOdGZTVXczY00?usp=sharing

Appreciate all the support!

Comment: I have also tried changing the resolution and scaling down to 1920x1080 but it didn't do anything but make everything bigger.